# How can I update the statistics of a table in cockroachdb

Tags: sql, database, cockroachdb, query-planner

In cockroachdb when I `explain` my query i see this

```
root@:26257/management_console_production> explain select * from clusters;
                                    info
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  distribution: local
  vectorized: true

  • scan
    estimated row count: 40 (100% of the table; stats collected 8 days ago)
    table: clusters@clusters_pkey
    spans: FULL SCAN
(7 rows)


Time: 2ms total (execution 2ms / network 0ms)
```

It shows above that stats were collected 8 days ago, how do i refresh the table statistics?

Answer (score 0):

In CRDB the cost based optimizer uses these statistics to make better query plans.
Table statistics are refreshed automatically based on usage patterns and some cluster settings

```
sql.stats.automatic_collection.fraction_stale_rows  (Target fraction of stale rows per table that will trigger a statistics refresh)

sql.stats.automatic_collection.min_stale_rows   (Target minimum number of stale rows per table that will trigger a statistics refresh)
```

You can manually update table statistics using `CREATE STATISTICS` or `ANALYZE`

```
root@:26257/management_console_production> analyze clusters;
ANALYZE


Time: 1.012s total (execution 1.012s / network 0.000s)

root@:26257/management_console_production> explain select * from clusters;
                                      info
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  distribution: local
  vectorized: true

  • scan
    estimated row count: 41 (100% of the table; stats collected 4 seconds ago)
    table: clusters@clusters_pkey
    spans: FULL SCAN
(7 rows)
```

See more about how table statistics works [here](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v23.1/cost-based-optimizer?_gl=1*tn8wlq*_ga*MzI2ODIzMTM2LjE2Mjg3ODU0ODE.*_ga_WPTKE58Z5D*MTY5NTE1MjA0Ni45MS4xLjE2OTUxNTIwNTQuMC4wLjA.#control-statistics-refresh-rate)